# when parent thread sleep does sub threads also sleep?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sleep, task-parallel-library

when parent thread sleep does sub threads also sleep ?

Now main thread is UI
I create 20 sub threads inside main thread with task factory (lets call threads 2)
Inside of this 20 sub threads i create another 10 sub threads again with sub factory (lets call threads 3)

Now inside of this threads 2 i have infinite loop. Inside of infinite loop checking whether threads 3 completed or not. If completed dispose completed thread and start another thread. I am using 250 ms sleep for each checking inside infinite while loop. So when threads 2 in sleep does also threads 3 sleep or they are independent. Here the code you can see.

```
while (true)
{
    int irActiveThreadCount = 0;
    int irFinishedLast = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < irPerMainSiteThreadCount; i++)
    {
        if (MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, i] == null)
        {
            irFinishedLast = i;
            break;
        }
        if (MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, i].IsCompleted == true)
        {
            irFinishedLast = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < irPerMainSiteThreadCount; i++)
    {
        if (MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, i] != null)
            if (MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, i].IsCompleted == false)
            {
                irActiveThreadCount++;
            }
    }

    if (irFinishedLast > -1)
    {
        var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            fcStartSubPageCrawl(srMainSiteURL, srMainSiteId, irWhichMainTask);
        });
        lock (lockerMainSitesArray)
        {
            if (MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, irFinishedLast] != null)
                MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, irFinishedLast].Dispose();
            MainSitesTaskList[irWhichMainTask, irFinishedLast] = newTask;
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(250);

    srQuery = "myquery";
    using (DataSet dsTemp = DbConnection.db_Select_Query(srQuery))
    {
        if (dsTemp != null)
            if (dsTemp.Tables.Count > 0)
                if (dsTemp.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put all of "WPF - TPL - C# 4.0" in your titles. Use tags for that.

Comment: First off, this sounds like a very thread-heavy architecture; are you sure you need all those threads? Any time you're wasting an entire thread that is just sitting there sleeping most of the time is a really bad sign; you wouldn't allocate a million byte array and then never put anything in it, but that's exactly what you're doing when you make an idle thread. Second, I don't understand why you are asking the question here. *You've already written the code; just run it and see what it does.* If the "child" threads do not go to sleep, you'll know the answer.

Comment: Eric Lippert i am also asking the approach for keeping certain number of threads alive all the time.

Comment: Sleeping is a lame way to wait. Use a proper wait function.

Comment: Sounds way too complex for a crawler. Create a task list and throw that at a pool of threads.

Comment: David Heffernan what is proper wait function ?

Comment: David's point is that there are **lots** of ways to make one thread wait on another. Use them! That is way better than this crazy system of sleeping for a while, waking up, going back to sleep, waking up... Instead, make an object that signals threads, have one thread wait for the signal and another thread activate the signal. Let the operating system deal with the thread management; you don't have to do all that stuff. Any time you see someone calling Sleep on a thread should be waving a big red flag that says "this guy is not efficiently managing his threads". There's a better way.

Comment: To keep a number of threads alive for use later, **do not do it yourself**. Use a thread pool. That's what it is for. Based on your question it sounds like (1) you don't have very much experience working with threads, and (2) you are trying to re-invent a whole bunch of technology that already exists and has been carefully tuned by experts. You are using the Task Parallel Library to represent your problem I see, so let *it* worry about figuring out how many threads to create to most efficiently solve the problem.

Comment: can you tell me that how would you make a threading which will crawl 1 million url. i really wonder your approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "parent" thread really. One thread starts another, but then there's no particular relationship between them. For example, the starting thread can terminate without any of the new threads dying.

The starting thread sleeping definitely doesn't affect any other thread.

Comment: thanks for answer. i just wonder this. is this approach good for keeping certain number of threads alive ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: No... don't just tell threads to sleep for the sake of 'hanging on' to them. There are pooling methods (see MSDN: Threadpool) that allow your app to 'keep a handle' on a thread.

Comment: ye but pooling does not let you keep certain number of threads alive

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: The whole point of a thread pool is that it *does* keep a number of threads alive, waiting for more work.

Comment: can you tell me that how would you crawl 1 million url with thread pool

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: If I were forced to do it on a single machine I'd probably use a producer/consumer queue such as BlockingCollection in .NET 4.

Comment: yes forced on single computer. but how are you going to start threads with even using BlockingCollection  ? how many thread will you start ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: That would depend on how many network connections I wanted to have open at a time - which would depend on my network connection itself, and also the URLs. (I'd try to avoid having too many open connections to a single host at a time, for example.)

Comment: can you tell me that in thread pool are you able to see how many threads are running. you are always giving un clear answers :D if there is a better way i would like to move it.

Comment: Isn't starting 1 million threads more time consuming than having them wait as Monster did ?

Comment: @Skuta: Who said anything about a million threads? I said I'd use a thread pool.

Comment: @JonSkeet Isn't there a different between foreground and background threads? I sometimes see people incorrectly refer to this difference using child/parent terminology. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: Foreground/background is only relevant in terms of whether a thread keeps the process alive. That's completely orthogonal to any concept of "parent/child".

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of parent and child threads. One implication of this is that the child threads don't sleep when the parent thread sleeps.

Comment: thanks for answer. i just wonder this. is this approach good for keeping certain number of threads alive ?

Comment: Why do you want to "keep a certain number of threads alive"? Generally threads live as long as they need to live to get their work done.

Comment: it is crawler. so i want to be able to set crawler agents count.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.Sleep(...)
```

only suspends the current Thread.

check here: [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)

so all other threads will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread is always totally independant. The only possible connection between threads is that when all the non-background thread finish, the program ends, so the background threads die. If a thread sleeps, the other threads continue working (and probably go faster, because there is one less thread working). If you need to sync threads, there are various classes to do it (in general locks (not a class), mutexes, semaphores...)

Answer (score 0):

The others are right, there is no concept of “parent threads” in .Net. And waiting on one thread doesn't cause other threads to wait (unless there is some synchronization involved, like using `lock`s).

But there's another point: your code doesn't create new threads, at least not necessarily. When you call `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, the task is usually scheduled on a thread pool thread. If there isn't any thread available and the number of threads didn't reach the maximum allowed number yet, new thread *is* created. But in other cases, it isn't. The task is either going to reuse existing idle thread, or it's going to wait, until one becomes available.